# Viewing process command line arguments in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a web service which runs in a app pool in IIS. Whenever I try to debug this web service I attach it to the visual studio debugger. However, the problem is there are multiple `w3wp.exe` (which hosts the web service) and I don't know which one to attach to. As a workaround, I first open the task manager (which has process command line as one of the column) check which of the mutiple `w3wp.exe` is hosting my app pool, note down its PID and then attach to the process with that PID from visual studio. Is there any better way to do this? Can I view the `w3wp.exe` command line parameters from visual studio 'attach to process' window itself? I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: You can use process explorer to do this.

Comment: Close vote with "Off topic"? Is debugging not related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

For Window 2008/Vista/7 (IIS 7.0/7.5)

- IIS 7.0/7.5 shipped with a new utility called AppCmd which serve as a command line server management utility.
- This tool located in %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe
- To list current worker process Id’s along with it’s corresponding site use
  the below command

  `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list wp`
- Once you know your application worker process Id, you select the correct worker process from “Attach to Process” dialog on Visual Studio

Hope it does help.